# Distribute discount coupons for our app on AppStore (sent via email)

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

As a developer (with Apple Developer program membership), is there a way to give discount coupons for an app sold on the AppStore?

Example use case: some users who bought many of our apps in the past contact us by email, and we would like to offer them 20% off if they purchase a new app. Is there a way to send them a discount coupon for a specific new app via email?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send out 20% discount coupons for App Store app purchases.

You have the choice of either using [App Store promo codes](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev50869de4a) that gives the user the app for free, or using [App Store offer codes](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=dopmcbjk) that discounts in-app subscriptions for the first term.

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct that there are a maximum of 100 promo codes? (A solution would be to charge these twenty 'VIP' loyal customers outside of AppStore with 20% or 50% discount who asked for it, and to give them a promo code... but I don't think this would be allowed by Apple?).